# Java, string to accept only letters and "if" statement

Tags: java

This is the code I have in a setName() method which I want to only accept letters (not digits)

```
      playerName = ""; 
      if (playerName.isDigit)
      {System.out.println("Please enter letters only");
       }
```

I am getting an error message which says "illegal parenthesised expression.

Comment: `if (playerName.isDigit)` does not look right to me?

Comment: I am pretty sure that `String` does not have a method called `isDigit` and even if it did it would require `()` - try loops through the individual Characters testing each one - see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit(char)

Answer (score 1):

`String` type doesn't have `isDigit` property. Use the following code to check if your variable contains digits.

```
if (playerName.matches(".*\\d+.*")) {
    System.out.println("Please enter letters only");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will work for you :

```
public static void setName ( String playerName ){
    if (playerName.matches(".*\\d.*") || playerName.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("Please enter letters only");
    } else {
        //Your code here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Lambda expression` to check whether the input string contains only character or not. In your `setName()` method, do the following

```
playerName="abcd";             //Take playerName from user input or as method argument

if(playerName==null || playerName.equals("") || !playerName.chars().allMatch(Character::isLetter))
        System.out.println("Please enter letters only");

else{

    //Do your work if someone enters name containing only letters.

}
```

Answer (score -1):

There's no `isDigit` method in `String.class` in Java, but there're lots of ways to do it.

Take a look: https://mkyong.com/java/java-how-to-check-if-a-string-is-numeric/